# Ubuntu 20.4.1: TTY's hang on cursor

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, tty

I recently updated to ubuntu 20.4.1 from 18.4. When I switch to a TTY with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, all I get is a black screen with a blinking cursor (underscore) which doesn't react to any keyboard input. I'm used to getting a login prompt as one would when logging in using `ssh` to a remote server. How can I fix this?

**EDIT: Additional information**

```
$ systemctl is-enabled getty@.service
enabled
```

```
$ journalctl -u getty@tty3.service
-- Logs begin at Sun 2019-07-14 23:09:57 CEST, end at Fri 2020-10-02 13:22:08 CEST. --
-- No entries --
```

<s>Other tty terminals (4-6) act the same.</s> [ not entirely correct, see below ]

**EDIT 2: Additional information**

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/tty3
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

TTY terminals 3, 4, and 5 only show a blinking cursor (underline) and don't react to any keyboard input.
On 6, I can type, but it does nothing except showing it on the screen. No command is being run, no login prompt that I can see.
<kbd>CtRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> only shows me

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journals
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, A/B files, C/D blocks
```

Where `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are some large integers I see no point in typing out here.

**Edit: Additional Information**
I suddenly started having trouble with the touchpad after waking up from sleep. It's much slower and the right-click via two finger touch didn't work. Following instructions from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788928), where a proposed fix is to just quickly switch to TTY 3 and back, the problem only starts occurring after the system went to sleep once and woke back up. I'm assuming the problems are related.

Comment: The information has been updated.

Comment: Hmm... thanks - have you messed with either the `NAutoVTs` or `ReserveVT` parameters in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` ?

Comment: No, freshly upgraded from 18.04 it and didn't mess with any of those.

Comment: Hit Enter? See if a process had it open? `sudo lsof /dev/tty3`

Comment: @waltinator: As I wrote, the terminals are not responding to any keyboard input. I added the output of `lsof` to the question.